# Using US Military Common Access Card (CAC) Personal Identity Verification (PIV) for authentication in Drupal

Tags: php, authentication, drupal-modules, cac

I have a requirement to enable logging into a new Drupal powered site using the military Common Access Card/Personal Identify Verification system.

I have come across this module: http://drupal.org/sandbox/larquin/1292622 but there is no code.

Is there a module for Drupal available? If not, does anyone know of any PHP (or for that matter any other language) sample code I can take a look at to base a module on?

Or, is there another approach to supporting this authentication approach that does not require a dedicated module? (e.g. ActiveDirectory? Apache configuration? etc)

Comment: So far the only information I've found on the subject: http://www.cantongroup.com/personal-identity-verification

Answer (score 2):

Drupal supports using CAS for logins, and CAS supports using X.509 certificates.

https://drupal.org/project/cas

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend contacting the people from Canton Group. The owner of the project at Drupal.org that you found is Micah Adams (nicknamed larquin) and is actually working for the Canton Group (http://www.cantongroup.com/personal-identity-verification)

Chances are that you might need to pay for this module, but that might be cheaper than writing it yourself.